# Getting hardware info in nim-lang

Tags: nim-lang

What is the most elegant way to get hardware info, such us GPU name, CPU name, RAM in nim? I haven't found a library and not really sure how to implement it from pure nim

Comment: There is none actually. I am writing mine based on shell's program `neofetch` https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch

Comment: Which OS do you want to target? The three major ones: Windows, Linux, macOS?
What kind of output do you want? CLI, GUI, Web? What would a pure Nim version brings over shell scripts? What have you tried to do so far? Your question doesn't show any research effort and is imprecise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to search for Nim packages, you should look first at:

1. [awesome-nim: A curated list of packages](https://github.com/ringabout/awesome-nim)
2. the `nimble search` functionality. Ex: `nimble search hardware cpu`
   I have found the [pkg/sysinfo package](https://github.com/treeform/sysinfo) and [pkg/psutil-nim](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/psutil-nim/tree/master/tests) which does probably what you want.

Shell scripts are usually faster and more adapted for this kind of application. There are many CLI applications that you can adapt or leverage directly.
On Linux, you can get hostname and model information with `hostnamectl`.
There are other utilities that aggregate hardware information, the most well-known is probably `neofetch`. It has many variants, see: https://alternativeto.net/software/neofetch/

Based on neofetch, I have written a small script that works on Linux only:

```nim
import std/[strutils, strformat, osproc]

type
  MyComputerInfo = object
    os: string
    host: string
    kernel: string
    cpu: string
    gpu: string


proc cacheUnameInfo*(): tuple[os: string, host: string, kernel: string] =
  ## Only defined for posix systems
  when defined(posix):
    let (output, errorCode) = execCmdEx("uname -omnr")
    if errorCode != 0:
      echo fmt"`uname -omnr` command failed, with Error code: {errorCode}"
      quit(2)
    let outSeq: seq[string] = output.split(' ')
    var arch: string = outSeq[3]
    stripLineEnd(arch)
    let
      os = arch & ' ' & outSeq[2]
      host = outSeq[0]
      kernel = outSeq[1]
    return (os, host, kernel)

proc getGpuInfo*(): string =
  when defined(posix):
    var (gpu_driver_name, exitCode) = execCmdEx("""lspci -nnk | awk -F ': ' \ '/Display|3D|VGA/{nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr {printf $2 ", "; exit}'""")
    if exitCode == 0:
      gpu_driver_name = gpu_driver_name.split(",")[0]
      if gpu_driver_name == "nvidia":
        var (gpu_name, exitCodeSmi) = execCmdEx("nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader")
        if exitCodeSmi != 0:
          echo "nvidia-smi command failed with exit code: {exitCodeSmi}"
          quit(2)
        return gpu_name
      return gpu_driver_name.toUpperAscii()
    else:
      echo fmt"GpuInfo error code: {exitCode}"
      quit(2)

proc getCpuInfo*(): string =
  when defined(posix):
    var (cpu_name, _) = execCmdEx("""cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk -F '\\s*: | @' '/model name|Hardware|Processor|^cpu model|chip type|^cpu type/ { cpu=$2; if ($1 == "Hardware") exit } END { print cpu }' "$cpu_file" """)
    return cpu_name

proc `$`(mci: MyComputerInfo): string =
  ## Nice Output of a `MyComputerInfo` object
  for name, val in fieldPairs(mci):
    if $val != "":
      result.add name.capitalizeAscii()
      result.add ": "
      result.add ($val).strip(leading=false, chars = {'\n'})
      result.add "\n"
  result.strip(leading=false, chars = {'\n'})

when isMainModule:
  var mci: MyComputerInfo
  (mci.os, mci.host, mci.kernel) = cacheUnameInfo()
  mci.gpu = getGpuInfo()
  mci.cpu = getcpuInfo()
  echo mci
```

On my computer, I get:

```
Os: GNU/Linux x86_64
Host: localhost
Kernel: 5.15.0-78-generic
Cpu: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7
Gpu: HEWLETT-PACKARD COMPANY TIGERLAKE-LP GT2 [IRIS XE GRAPHICS] [103C:880D]
```

We could replace the awk's calls in `execCmdEx` by Nim parsing procedures for more Nim purity. We could add a configurator (with a CLI parser, or a DSL) so that the user can select the options he wants to print out. I leave the rest to you.